# MySQL Query Multiple Items from same table given value from another row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This has gone far beyond mySQL skills. I have tried table joins but I just can't get it right - if it's even possible.

Basically I have a table...

```
ID -|- SubId -|- Str
 -----------------
1   |    0    |  Str1
2   |    1    |  Str2
3   |    2    |  Str3
4   |    3    |  Str4
```

If I know the value of say, "Str 3" is there an easy way to get:

- All rows where sub ID = 2
- All rows where ID =2
- All rows where ID = the Sub ID of row 2

... and so on?

Please ask if you don't understand and I will clarify further, obviously trying to do this with one query

EDIT:

I will try to explain better.

Lets assume we have a slug, let this slug be the value of say, Str3. I would like to know if there is a way to then query the database, getting the records where Str = "Str3"

Is it then possible to follow the "hierachy". I.e., Since Str3 (ID:3) has a Sub ID of 2, can the query the go and fetch the row with ID:2.

Further, can it then look at the ID:2 row and see that it also has a Sub ID, "1", then fetch the row with the ID:1

I have this further explains what is needed.

If the above is possible, is it also possible to continue the "other way"

E.g. From "Str3" we can see that the row has ID:3. Can we then fetch all rows with Sub ID:3.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Do you have any existing queries to help us understand?

Comment: You are representing hierarchical data with the "[adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)" model, which requires recursion to completely traverse the structure; however, unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL does not support recursive functions.  It's usually best (if possible) to use a model more suited to relational databases, such as "[nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)" or a table of the graph's "[transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)".

Comment: A useful reference: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: `All rows where ID = the Sub ID of row 2` Do you really mean "of row 2" or "of row with ID = 2"? What do you mean with "and so on"?

Comment: Please post your table schema. You can use a `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table;`

Comment: I have attempted to clarify by editing the original question. Thank you for the references I will have to adapt one if I cannot make this work.